# Run methods after client's request

Tags: python, flask

To minimize the request time I want to execute the method after return 200 to client.

```
@app.route('/register', methods=['POST'])
def register():
      #code and code
      return 200
      send_email_with_validation_url()
```

How can I do it? With threads?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it with threads, but without some control you could end up with lots of threads choking resources. You could also end up with processes crashing without you being aware.

This is the job for a queue system. [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) would be a good fit. Something along the lines of:

```
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('tasks', broker='amqp://guest@localhost//')

@app.task
send_email_job(address):
    send_email_with_validation_url()


@app.route('/register', methods=['POST'])
def register():
      #code and code
      send_email_job.delay(address)
      return 200
```

In this example, `send_email_job` will be scheduled run in the background (in a different thread or process or even machine if you want) with the given arguments and your server will return immediately.

Comment: and after_requests ? cant handle with that?

Comment: It will run after the request is served (see my edit)

Comment: @Urbester The documentation, http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/53/, states that `after_request` executes on all requests

Comment: This solution is asynchronous? or will block my request?

Comment: It is asycnronous. It will not block. Have a look at the Celery docs.

Answer (score 0):

Celery is great but if the task isn't critical asyncio would be a great option to explore, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53663219/runtimeerror-this-event-loop-is-already-running/53665331#53665331)